# How to setup my own Git Server?

Tags: git

I'm getting confused about how to have a Git Server in my own machine.

I need to setup a central server with all Git repos, like Subversion. What is my best option?

Install Gitosis?

Answer (score 4):

Well that actually depends on a couple of factors..

if it is a multiuser environment on which you DON'T necessarily want all people that have GIT repos to also have SHELL access, then i would recommend Gitolite.
(Gitosis is almost as good as dead now).

much like gitosis, Gitolite allows for multiuser envs with many repos and easy user and privilege management by using ssh keys, without the need for the users to have shell access to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a Github-like experience inside your environment, but don't want to pay for [Github](https://about.gitlab.com/), Gitlab is pretty reasonable.

LDAP-Auth, RBAC, Config-Management options available (Chef, at least), Pull-request workflow ("Merge Requests" for them...) all make this a viable option.

Additionally, it's an Open-Source project with a company behind it.

A downside is that it trails GitHub in features.  This means that if you're excited by something new that GitHub has done, you're going to have to wait for it, or contribute some work yourself.